# C# Active Directory, Login in a specific OU

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to login in a only specific OU, but not in previous OU.

My parent function is:

```c#
    if (Autentificado("LDAP://localhost/DC=ic,DC=enterprise,DC=us", user, pass, "cn=SpecificPeople,ou=Users,ou=Aplications,dc=ic,dc=enterprise,dc=us") != "")
    {
                    
                    return "OK";
    }
```

It contains server direction with path, user, pass and a string for the "memberof" filter:

```c#
public static string Autentificado(string ldap, string usr, string pwd,string member)
        {
          try
            {
                DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ldap, usr, pwd);
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
                {
                                   
                  Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(memberof=" + member + "))"
                
                };
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
                return result.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
            }
            catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException cex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            return "";
           

        }
```

It return the correct user of "OU=Users", but it return users of others OU or DC. I want that people only can login in the "OU=Users".

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**
I think that the problem is with the structure of my LDAP and the filter of the DirectorySearcher:

```
DC=US
 -DC=enterprise
  -DC=ic
   -OU=Apps
     -OU=1
     -OU=2
     -OU=USERS
```

If i use: *SearchScope.Subtree*, it search in all directories.*SearchScope.OneLevel*, it search in the DC=enterprise or in all OU=Apps (if i'm not mistaken).*SearchScope.Base*, it search in the DC=US.

I want that the search will be only in the *OU=USERS*, and not in the others Directories (OU=1, OU=2).

**UPDATE 2**

My GETUSER funtion is:

```c#
DirectoryEntry usercheck = GetUser(user, pass,"LDAP://someIP:389/CN=qualifiers,OU=USERS,OU=Aplications,DC=ic,DC=enterprise,DC=us");
```

And in the "DirectoryEntry searchRoot", i need to set an user and password for enter in the LDAP. If not, it take me error:

```c#
using (DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(rootWeAreLooking,"ic\\"+userName,pass, AuthenticationTypes.None))
```

I see that this could be work, but it search in all directories of *OU=Aplications* yet.

I think that i need to filter by *CN=qualifiers*, but i don't know how.

**Update 3**

I need to try properly, but i think that i do the correct filter:

```
searcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(memberof=CN=qualifiers,OU=USERS,OU=Aplications,DC=ic,DC=enterprise,DC=us)(sAMAccountName={0}))", userName);
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more. I dont understand the last sentence: `It return the correct user of "ou=Users", but it return users of others OU or DC. I want that people only can login in the "OU=Users".` What do you mean with `I want that people only can login in the "OU=Users`? Do you mean that only users which are in the OU=User are allowed to LOGIN into your LDAP?

Comment: Exactly, i only want people in the OU=User. Y try to use:
search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Base
But retreive nothing...

Comment: Did you check my new Version?

Comment: Yes,i have checked it. But i have the same trouble. I think that my problem is with the structure and the filter of the DirectorySearcher. I have updated my question. Anyway, thanks for your support :)

Comment: Ok. So what arguments are you passing to the `GetUser()` Method? I need to know the exactly argument of the *"FullOrganisationUnitPath"*. Be shure the Path points to OrganisationUnit *"User"*. We gonna get it working xD

Comment: Morning! Just updated. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Be shure you set the *SearchScope* to `SearchScope = SearScope.OneLevel;`. Also try this LDAP-Path instead of yours: `"LDAP://OU=USERS,OU=Aplications,DC=ic,DC=enterprise,DC=us"`. The next thing you need to tell me is, what kind you AD-Object is qualifiers? (Group,computer,user, etc). Made small changes to the code

Comment: CN=qualifiers is a group of users that is in OU=USERS

Comment: You mean a group which "contains" users which is in the OU=USERS, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, for example:

user1 : CN=qualifiers,OU=USERS,OU=Aplications,DC=ic,DC=enterprise,DC=us

Comment: I see that if i meke the filter with "sAMAccountName", it take me TRUE.
I think i can filter by CN=qualifiers too, not?

Comment: The filter for the group would be `(&(ObjectCategory=group)(cn=qualifiers))`. What username you are passing? Are you passing the LOG-IN name or der CommonName? My method GetUser only works for CommonName, which is an easy fix

Comment: I pass the login-name. Finally, y fix the problem with the filter in my **update 3**. @manuchao  , thanks a lot for the help of these days. I want to vote you, but i can't yet xD.

Comment: The Log-In name x). Well the problem is solved... Do this part as "Done".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I do this filter and works for me:

```c#
searcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(memberof=CN=qualifiers,OU=USERS,OU=Aplications,DC=ic,DC=enterprise,DC=us)(sAMAccountName={0}))", userName);
```

And in my LDAP path, i put the root path directory

```
DC=ic,DC=enterprise,DC=us
```

Comment: It also should work with the code above. Try to replace `cn` in the filter with `sAMAccountName`, if you searching with the loginName

Answer (score 3):

So I just created this code which does the thing you want. I splitted the code into multiple methods, so you can use some singe functions like `ValidateUser` else where.

1. Find the user in the AD and the ou (root) you are searching in and make shure he exits
2. Now that we know that he is allowed to "LOGIN" we are validating his password against AD.
3. If all went fine, the user is in the `OU=USER` (in your case) and also the password is correct

   ```
   private void TestTheMethods()
   {
       //Search for the user, in the ou "user" 
       DirectoryEntry user = GetUser("FirstName LastName","FullOrganisationUnitPath");
       //Found user?
       if (user == null) { return; }

       //ValidateUser
       if (!ValidateUser(user, "userPassword")) { return; }
   }     

   public DirectoryEntry GetUser(string userName, string rootWeAreLooking = "")
   {
       DirectoryEntry user = null;

       using(DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(rootWeAreLooking))
       using(DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot))
       {
           searcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(cn={0}))",userName);
           //searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

           //SearchScope.Subtree --> Search in all nested OUs
           //SearchScope.OneLevel --> Search in the Ou underneath
           //SearchScope.Base    --> Search in the current OU

           search.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;

           SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
           if (result == null) { return null; }

           //Found user
           return result.GetDirectoryEntry();
       }
   }

   public Boolean ValidateUser(DirectoryEntry entry, string pwd)
   {
       Boolean isValid = false;

       try
       {
           DirectoryEntry validatedUser = new DirectoryEntry(entry.Path, entry.Name.Remove(0,3), pwd);
           //Check if we can access the Schema
           var Name = validatedEntry.SchemaEntry;
           //User exits, username is correct and password is accepted
           isValid = true;
       }
       catch(DirectoryServicesCOMException ex)
       {
           isValid = false;
           ///User wrong? wrong password?
       }

       return isValid;
   }
   ```

Comment: This is correct, but this search in the previous OU and DC too,right? I need too see in the last OU/CN

Comment: Do you want to get the users which are ONLY in the *user* organisationUnit and NOT the nested OUs? I dont understand what you realy want. Can you show us some examples?

Comment: Exactly, i want only see in the "OU=users",  but not in the nested OUs. Is this possible?

Comment: Easy fix :P. Just set the SearchScope to Base. I updated the code

Comment: Or use `search.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;`